# Everything is disabled under BI Publisher Menu

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

Everything is disabled under BI publisher menu. 12.214.00.000 is my BI version and it's 32bit
Word 16.0.14326.21092 32bit

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to load sample XML data first; once you do that, the rest of icons is *enabled*:

[image]

Comment: The requirements is to add functionality to existing RTF file

Comment: Doesn't matter - you'll still first have to load XML data.

Comment: But in 12.210.000.000 we have an option to edit existing RTF without loading XML data

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't know. Did you - at least - *try* to load data and see what happens?

Comment: We use Build 12.214.00.000 and we still have to load Sample XML before the other controls are available.